# MS-Access 2007 query run-time error

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have an MS-Query that causes a problem at run-time error # 3071
The message is long, here is the begining:

> The expression is typed incorrectly, or is too complex to be evaluated.

The query has many columns and functions, and with some trial and error I have isolated the offending part of the query to be:

```
...
And
[Component.Serial])>=Val(([Forms]![frm_RptFilter_Components].[fldAutoSeq])) 
And 
([Component.Serial])<=Val(([Forms]![frm_RptFilter_Components].[fldAutoSeq2])))
```

the name: frm_RptFilter_Components is the correct name of the form where input comes from and the name: fldAutoSeq, fldAutoSeq2 are the names of the fields on that form.

The expression Forms... is correct and used in other parts of the query. So spelling is not the problem.

The column in the database is "Serial" and it is an integer. It is being compared to a form field (text field).

I can execute the offending part by itself as in:

```
SELECT * FROM Component
WHERE ((
    [Component.Serial])>=Val(([Forms]![frm_RptFilter_Components].[fldAutoSeq])) 
    And 
    ([Component.Serial])<=Val(([Forms]![frm_RptFilter_Components].[fldAutoSeq2])))
```

So, I am confused. Had the offending part contained syntax errors, it SELECT above should not have worked. However, when removing that part, the original big query gives an error.

My guess is that when the query is run from the subform, the fields are not passed correctly to the query and being numeric fields, this causes the problem.

Do you see the reason I am getting the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
And
[Component.Serial]>=[Forms]![frm_RptFilter_Components].[fldAutoSeq]
And 
[Component.Serial]<=[Forms]![frm_RptFilter_Components].[fldAutoSeq2]
```

*and* specify these two parameters as Long:

```
[Forms]![frm_RptFilter_Components].[fldAutoSeq] 
[Forms]![frm_RptFilter_Components].[fldAutoSeq2]
```

Comment: Very clever. It worked! I am not well versed in MS-Access by any chance but it was not obvious to me!

Comment: It's an old trick. It works by narrowing down the possible options for input from the form fields.